# Check Constraints on DataRow Add

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, datarow

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ValueOne",typeof(string)){AllowDBNull = false});
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ValueTwo",typeof(string)){AllowDBNull = false});

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["ValueOne"] = "Test1";
    if (dt.Rows.CanAdd(row))
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Is there some way to Check if a Row Can be Added before trying to add the row?

Comment: Are you asking for a `dt.Rows.CanAdd`?

Comment: I think he wants a function that will automatically check to make sure that non-nullable fields have non-null values, something like

    if (row.IsValid())

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automatically do this.  What would you do instead? If you just want to skip the row you could put it into a try/catch but make sure you only catch the specific exception.